# A word which comes with meaning like "something that works in parallel"

Tags: single-word-requests

I need to write about a technology which works with another in parallel.

What is a single word which means something like "something which works in parallel" or "works in parallel"?

Comment: Do you mean that your sentence would read "X is a Y technology" and Y is a word that means "something that works in parallel with other things"?

Comment: Just throwing some words out there to stimulate thinking on this: compatible, symbiotic, cooperative, coordinated, synergistic, concurrent, synchronized, shared, ...

Comment: actually I want a noun word .. well, I have a .net project which works in parallel with an asp.net project. So I needed to name that .net project in this way ".net collaboration" in an email .. (btw, collaborate would do :))

Comment: Parallel means "beside other." It comes from the Greek words *para allio-sis* which means "beside other."

Comment: @Ana, thank you very much for your valuable information :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that usually you'd need to specify "X works in parallel with Y".

Although you could say "X is a concurrent technology" if you qualified earlier what a concurrent technology was.

Answer (score 9):

Being a developer, the first word I'd think of would be `concurrent`, however you can also use:

- parallel
- synchronous
- simultaneously

Since you mentioned "writing about technology", I'd say that `concurrent` and `synchronous` would *technically* be the most correct in this situation.

wrt. [Tom's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12023/a-word-which-comes-with-meaning-like-something-that-works-in-parallel/12024#12024), I really wouldn't feel the need to explain the meaning of concurrent (unless it was an introductory manual), because most developers (sysadmins, etc.) would already know what that meant.

Comment: Did you mean _synchronous_ instead of _asynchronous_ (@Jez's answer)?

Comment: Yeah. My bad. Fixed.

Comment: In a technical sense I don't think you could use the words synchronous and concurrent interchangeably. 'synchronous' would usually be used to describe a technology that relies on a clock signal to trigger events.

Comment: Tom: `concurrent` is still the best here, as I've mentioned.

Comment: Actually, *asynchronous* may be the correct word in a programmer's sense. An asynchronous task can work independently of the main task, not needing to stop and synchronize. A synchronous or *blocking* task might spend long periods waiting for another task and thus not be operating in the most parallel manner.

Answer (score 2):

The most befitting word for your situation is "collateral", see below for derivation

Collateral derives from the Latin roots

col- = "together with/in"

later- = "side"

Therefore, it literally means "together at the side, or parallel"

Web definitions:

col·lat·er·al Adjective /kəˈlatərəl/ /kəˈlatrəl/

1. Additional but subordinate; secondary
   E.g. the collateral meanings of a word
2. Situated side by side; parallel
   E.g. collateral veins

Answer (score 2):

Jez: "synchronous" means together in time" (syn + chron + ous)

Potatoswatter: "complementary" would vaguely suggest the connotation of "supporting"

Tom & Aviral: "concurrent" could fit the bill, as it literally means "running together with"
               (con + curr + ent)

Alex: "simultaneous" doesn't quite convey the deliberation that "collateral" and "concurrent"
       do. Such a deliberation is necessary when talking of something that "works together
       with something."

Comment: hey thats significant :) more elaborated .. I have accepted concurrence :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "simultaneously" fits perfectly?

Comment: if its **technology** I would rather choose .. **Concurrence** or **collaborated** etc :) so I have accepted the same answer .. anyways thanks for the useful discussion :)

Answer (score 0):

*Complementary* is the most likely choice, but we might need more context.

Comment: well I have chosen Concurrence .. which suits more incase of **technologies** :) thanks for useful discussion..

Comment: @infant: Concurrence means two things happen at the same time, simultaneously. Complementary means they benefit each other. The meanings are quite different, so be sure to choose what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

'Something which is synchronous'?