# What is the true antonym of "successive"?

Tags: antonyms

What is the true antonym of "successive"?

Did the the "true" sound weird?

Well everywhere I looked, I only found subjective antonyms like Broken, Discontinuous, Infrequent, Intermittent, Interrupted, Unconsecutive etc.. 
But what is the "true" antonym?

For example, if the subjective antonym of "Concentrated" is "Dilute", then the True antonym of "concentrated" is "dispersed". Hope you understand.
Or the True antonym of "Forward" is "Backward" or "moving in reverse"

Likewise, if "successive" was understood as something in relation to "progressive", what is its antonym? Definitely something in the lines of "anti-succession" or likewise.

If it does not in fact exist in the English vocabulary, will I be wrong in the convenient neologism "anti-succession"?

The premise is where I was drafting a question in the Microsoft forum, answers.microsoft.com, in which I wanted to know how to view elements in the clipboard. The elements are supposed to be stacked and displayed in "succession" but I was only seeing the last element (that was stored in succession to the previous element(s) that was strangely extant). So to draft the question I had to address the elements that were lost or not displayed, that were in fact stored previously/opposite to succession.

So what is the true antonym or opposite of succession? Thanks immensely!

- well sorry, my bad. well here it is:
  I don't just want the programmers at Microsoft to know that, the "previous elements" seem to have dropped out of display (of which I could have just said "the elements prior to the only one displayed are not.. err don't seem to be there). I want to specify that the "order" of elements don't "stretch back" from the one's displayed. Now I hadn't hoped to expect that the Programmers at Microsoft are "linguistic morons". The correct word usage may be essential in their coming with the accurate response ye?
- here it is Trevor. Well what I meant was this:
  the clipboard programme is supposed to list out all the clipboard elements in order of their employment. so imagine the carriages of a train, starting from the engine (if the engine is the "middle" carriage). there are 5 carriages before/behind the engine and 5 after/in front of the engine. in my case, the problem is not the carriages in front of the engine, but the carriages behind the engine. I want the programmers to know that the carriages behind the engine are not displayed, and not just "displayed", but they are not displayed in the way they should: in order. or the backward order. now is there a word for backward order? "reverse order" could be a solution, but is there a word, an antonym for the forward flow of things, or "succession". there. cheers!

counter-successive sounds perfect thanks indeed Kris. But I still haven't come across the availability of a single word. but thank you all!

Comment: Yes, the "true" sounds weird. There is no ISO standard for antonyms. Furthermore, "subjective" is not an antonym of "true"; and antonymy, like division, is not defined for every possible argument.

Comment: I really don't see how _dilute_ is a “subjective” antonym of _concentrated,_ nor how _dispersed_ is “true” – in the context of chemistry, that isn't true at all. Likewise, I don't see how a “true” antonym is going to help you in the software context. So I'm not really sure what you're asking here.

Comment: Like some others who responded, I don't understand the meaning or importance of *true* and *subjective* in the question.

Also, and not to split hairs, I'm not sure if you want the antonym of *successive* or *succession*.

Finally, isn't the point that you want to know what happened to the *previous* elements - the ones copied to the clipboard prior to the last element? And if so, why not just say that?

Comment: not software context as such, but just to address the elements in a list. like the carriages in a train? the "reverse direction" of succession.. anti succession? sounds fitting

And yes Jeff, good solution but I hoped to use this opportunity for an intellectual discussion. It might sound morose to chase a word that doesn't seem to exist but what I've learnt about languages is that like how we can emanate all possible noises that can be heard, through the voice box, our forefathers penned down every possible situation in language. well, almost. or we'll have to do that job and fill the gap

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand anymore than before what exactly you're after. I don't understand what you mean by " I want to specify that the "order" of elements don't "stretch back" from the one's displayed."

Comment: If the "converse" of *clockwise* is *counter-clockwise*, surely a *successive* set of elements can be accessed in a *counter-successive* order?

Comment: What is *still* unclear about this Q?

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand what the question means. It's far too verbose and conversational, and it's just too difficult to figure out what's important. It also doesn't help that I can't see how it helps to look for a single word here – I think the questioner would fare much better with a concise description of the problem, _especially_ since he's working on a bug report. In particular, _don't_ “add additional details” as suggested by the close notice; there's too much extraneous detail already.

Comment: right... you may have a point..
now it's not so much that I needed to know the antonym or just the opposite of the event "successive". if successive is "down the track", then I needed to know how to define the "flow" of elements in the "other direction". comprende?
well happy to say that I've arrived at a coclusion according to a previous comment/solution here.
the answer is "counter successive"
My bug report: "Only the last element from the clip board is visible. I need them in the appropriately counter-successive order please. please look into this, thanks."
there.. and thanks to Kris! PEACE

Comment: Could "recursive" qualify as a potential antonym then?

Comment: There is no reverse to successive, because successive only says that the items are sequential, but does not indicate whether the items are arranged in a rising or a falling order. The lists "1,2,3" and "3,2,1" both show a set of successive numbers.

Comment: Btw, I read your entire (edited) question, and still did not understand what you wanted. Only after reading your comment to bib's answer did I understand that you want to know how to describe a list being showed in reversed order. In which case I suggest you simply write that "the list is being displayed in reverse order". And if you still want an antonym, then delete your entire question and replace it with something about "reverse order".

Answer (score 3):

If *[successive](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/successive)* means

> following another without interruption

then the antonym might be *[disjunctive](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disjunctive)*

> marked by breaks or disunity *a disjunctive narrative sequence*

An alternative might be *[discontinuous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discontinuous)*

> a (1) : not continuous  (2) : not continued : discrete *discontinuous features of terrain*
>
> b : lacking sequence or coherence

Comment: disjunctive least serves the purpose. think "reverse order" or "backward flow" or "streaming in reverse". not non-successive but the "opposite flow" of successive. hope this helped. thanks for your response.

Comment: all of the above addresses the "connection" of elements rather than the arrangement or order that I'm looking for. but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*Concentrated* has an inward direction to the concept (particles moving closer together and filling more of the space) while *dispersed* has an outwardness. Seems what you're looking for is an antonym that addresses the forward flow of *successive.* *Disjunctive* or *discontinuous* only contribute an opposite meaning to half of the concept of *successive* (the continuous part, but not the forward or progressive part).

They wouldn't have worked for your forum question but I think you're looking for something along the lines of *regressive* and *retrograde.* They both have that sense of flow/continuity as well as a reverse direction.

---

added:

Your post seems to ask two questions.
1. How could you have worded your forum question?
2. Is there a better antonym for *successive* than the ones you've found, an antonym that addresses more aspects of the concept of *successive* than just continuity?

It also seems that #1 gave rise to #2 out of sheer intellectual curiosity.

Answer to #2 already offered.

Answer to #1: It would have sufficed to ask about all the preceding elements (*all* emphasizing the reverse flow and that you are interested in more than just the few preceding elements) or about all the elements leading up to the one displayed (meaning all the elements from the 1st to the one displayed).

Comment: your response is the only closest to what I seek thanks. regressive or retrograde are along those lines but what is the correct alternative that I can fix in a sentence that addresses.. hey I think "regressive" does the trick! but I need to find a suitable synonym. thank you, SO VERY MUCH! hope a suitable word exists.

Answer (score 1):

The basic premise of your question is flawed; many words do not have "one true antonym".  This is because most words have multiple meanings or a spectrum of similar meanings with different semantic loads.  Even where a word has one clear meaning, that does not mean there is only one concept which stands in clear contrast to it.  Is "few" the true antonym of "many" or is "one"?

There are several ways in which multiple events could be shown not to be successive:

- There might be one large interruption in the sequence, with other conflicting events filling the gap
- Some or all of the events may happen in parallel
- There might only be one event

Which of these is truly not successive?  All of them (and the list is not exhaustive).  Which is most pertinent to you is entirely contextual.

Comment: no not the connection or obstruction. or the simultaneous occurrence or existence of elements. and not the existence of just one element. but thank you very much. appreciate it

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you and [this poster](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122897/a-word-which-means-the-opposite-of-something-that-works-in-parallel) are approaching the same words form opposite directions.

I would use **in parallel** to describe your circumstance.

Comment: no sorry this least approaches the solution. rather than parallel, I'm looking for something in the opposite flow or reverse. I think I've got a possible solution up there. "regressive" is a good solution, but I need to look for an equivalent term that fits in the sentence. regressive does indeed fit but it purports an incorrect meaning, like I'm complaining to the programmers that the elements are "reducing" (or similar). but regressive fits in the lines. thank you very much for you time and response!

Answer (score -1):

When wanting to refer to "the elements that were ... stored previously", I would have said "the **preceding** elements. But, in that context, I don't think you want the "opposite [of] **succession**", but rather the opposite of, perhaps, "following" or "subsequent".

The [definition](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=succession&title=21st) of "succession" is as follows:

> **succession *noun***
>   1a. a series of people or things that come, happen, etc one after the other;
>   1b. the process or an instance of this.
>   2a. the right or order by which one person or thing succeeds another;
>   2b. the process or act of doing this.
>   3. [not relevant]
>   **successional *adj.* successionally *adverb.* successionless *adj.***
>   **in succession** one after the other.
>   **in quick succession** quickly one after the other.

Note that, *by definition*, "**succession**" refers to "a *series* of people or things".

When you were wanting to view a list of items in the clipboard, they were stored *sequentially* - *i.e.* one after the other in the *sequence* in which they were placed in the clipboard. And, yes, you could describe them as stored *in succession* (one after the other), but any *order of succession* (order of storage) would be arbitrary because the items were unrelated.

So, bearing in mind that *succession* refers to a *series* of people or things:

1. You can't really have the opposite of a *series* in that context, so there can be no opposite of *succession*.
2. You weren't really interested in the *series*, but merely in the *preceding items* in the list, with the actual *order* or *sequence* being immaterial (if I understand correctly).

In those circumstances, you merely need a word that describes the items that were stored in the list prior to the item you were looking at, and I think **preceding** is therefore an apt choice.  You could alternatively referred to items that were stored *earlier than* or *prior to* the item referred to.

Having said that, one antonym of **successor** (*i.e.* the person or item that *follows* the current one) would be **predecessor** (*i.e.* the person or item that *precedes* (goes before) the current one).

Comment: certainly very very close to my premise, similar to a previous response. Thank you very much! the only correctioon in your response is that I was "really interested in the series". The opposite of the series of elements. the reverse. the elements in "anti" succession. But what I seek is a word that addresses this situation or description. thank you!