# Opposite of "successive": one-after-another in a forward order

Tags: single-word-requests

If the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are successive, what are the numbers 5, 4, 3, 2, 1?

> The ____ items are ...

Predecessive doesn't seem to be a word, nor antecessive (such weird attempts).

What's a word that means: each item occurs directly before the next item.

Similarly this word would be the opposite of consecutive.

Same meaning, but in the opposite direction; backwards instead of forwards.

Comment: I'm not aware of an adjective, but the usual prepositional phrase is _in reverse order_. It can't be used prenominally.

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122902/what-is-the-true-antonym-of-successive

Comment: Call it _countdown order_ if you don't like _reverse_.

Comment: The etymological opposite could be 'recessive'.  However, there is an ambiguity in the Latin preposition 're', which can mean 'back' in the sense of 'away from' or 'again'.  So 'Re' can indicate 'backwards' or it can indicate 'again', as in a 'recessive' gene, compared with the 'backwards' of an economic 'recession', in which the employment and 'GDP statistics go down from higher to lower numbers, which is exactly what you are after.  But if you want to be in the safe side, stick with Edwin Ashworth's "in reverse order".

Answer (score 1):

[Successive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/successive#Adjective) means "coming one after the other". To describe items as successive is to describe where they are (namely in consecutive places one after the other), not what they actually *are*. The numbers 5, 1, 22, 44, 3 would be successive if they were drawn in that order in a lottery draw.

Your sequence 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 is a **decreasing** sequence of **consecutive** numbers. (As far as I know, there is no single word which encapsulates the ideas of "consecutive numbers" and the sequence being decreaing.)

Comment: You're absolutely correct in your definition of successive and that's exactly the meaning I want to invert. If 5, 1, 22, 44, 3 were the successive numbers, what would 3, 44, 22, 1, 5 be?

Comment: Successive numbers can be increasing or decreasing numbers.

Comment: I think the point is not that the numbers increase or decrease, but the ordinal relationship is read forward or backward.  If I referred to Sears, Kmart, Walmart and Amazon as a successive list of largest retailers in the US, what do I refer to Amazon, Walmart, Kmart and Sears as? A ____ list?

Answer (score -1):

In the sequence "1, 2, 3, 4, 5" the numbers are said to be consecutive ([ref.](https://iq-faq.com/en/Q%26A/page=79bb1e168dd60f04e12acd254e03b0c0#s10)). However, they are also successive ("consecutive" implies "successive") ([ref.](https://iq-faq.com/en/Q%26A/page=79bb1e168dd60f04e12acd254e03b0c0#s0)).

There is no single word term for the reverse arrangement. A compound can be used, such as "inversely consecutive", but I do not think this is a defined mathematical term. In mathematics one would rather speak only tentatively  of a "reverse integer sequence" ("reverse consecutive integer sequence") ([ref.](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConsecutiveNumberSequences.html)).

The term "decreasing sequence of consecutive integers" is standard, however.